# Create an Excel Macros to Delete Rows based on the selected cells in a Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro however its not really working since the rows actually change during the delete. The user select any # of cells in a table. On run of the macros, just those rows which belong to the selected cells are deleted. Here is what I got to so far:

```
Sub DeleteSelectedRows()
Dim Cell As Range
With Sheet1
For Each Cell In Selection
        .Range(Cell.Address).EntireRow.Delete
Next Cell
End With
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You just need `Selection.EntireRow.Delete` no need to loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a `For Each` loop when modifying the collection, use a simpler `For` loop, starting at the last row index (or column index) and going backwards to the first index.

Make sure the loop is set to `Step -1` to go backwards.  The backwards direction is required because in Excel, when you delete a row/column, the remaining rows/columns move up/left, so all further indexes may be wrong after the first edit.

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = Selection

Dim firstRow as Integer
Dim lastRow as Integer

firstRow = rng.Row   
lastRow = rng.Rows(rng.Rows.Count).Row

Dim i as Integer   
For i = lastRow to firstRow Step -1
     Call ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Delete()    
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks this worked even better than Selection.areas when users highly multiple rows. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In some (probably rare) cases, a user could ctrl+click to select a non-contiguous range.  This code would account for that possibility, while still only deleting the rows that are actually selected:

```
Sub DeleteSelectedRows()

    Dim rArea As Range

    For Each rArea In Selection.Areas
        rArea.EntireRow.Delete
    Next rArea

End Sub
```